# I made a change to sqlite ntable and I was wondering how do I update it in my onupgrade?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I made a change to my DB Adaptor I added a new column and I was wondering how do I add it to all the people who have older versions of my app? Am I supposed to change DATABASE_CREATE with the column or do I just add it to onupgrade. If I am just supposed to add it to onupgrade can someone show me an example?

Thanks

Comment: First, update your static final database version to a higher value in your upgraded application - then in you SQLiteOpenHelper:s onUpgrade method you perform an [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html), adding the column.

Comment: okay I did that and it worked thanks :)

Comment: Jens, why don't you post that as an answer so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Increase your database version for your database, and in your on upgrade do something like this

```
if (oldVersion == 2)
    upgradeToVersion3();
```

Then in that method you can use `ALTER TABLE`. But I am not sure whether or not the version Android use actually has support for adding extra columns. If not, you'll have to rename the table, create the new table, and then do a page lookup with a `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) SELECT column1 FROM tmp_table`